# How do I modify this function

Tags: javascript

I modify this function but I want to be sure this is right because it suppose to take me to the next code question but it didn't  even after it printed the result as correct.

Modify this Function to return avg

```
function getAverageTestScore(scores) {
  let testScores = (scores[0] + scores[1]) / 2
  return testScores;
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */
const avg = getAverageTestScore([80, 100]);
console.log(avg, '<-- should be 90');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this function, it will accept unlimited number of inputs and return average of them

```js
function getAverageTestScore(...scores) {
  let result = 0;
  
  for(let score of scores) {
    result += score;
  }

  return result / scores.length;

}

let avg = getAverageTestScore(2, 2, 2);
console.log(avg) // 2
```